# Flutter : [!] Your app isn't using AndroidX

Tags: flutter

I ran my project and got this error, how should I fix it?

> Launching lib\main.dart on N9560 in debug mode... [!] Your app isn't
>   using AndroidX.
>   task 'assembleDebug'...

Comment: I am trying to follow the steps below but when I go to file Migrate, I don't see Android Studio X.

Comment: Open Android Studio.
Select Open an existing Android Studio Project.
Open the android directory within your app.
Wait until the project has been synced successfully. (This happens automatically once you open the project, but if it doesn’t, select Sync Project with Gradle Files from the File menu).
Select Migrate to AndroidX from the Refactor menu.
If you are asked to backup the project before proceeding, check Backup project as Zip file, then click Migrate. Lastly, save the zip file in your location of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow steps in below link:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: Yes I was trying to follow the steps in the link below. Please see my comments above. I don't see Android X in the refactor menu